# Use of unassigned local variable after going through a list

Tags: c#, list, json.net

```
List <State> states = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<State>> (json);

State state;
foreach(State i in states) {
if (i.StateID == Convert.ToInt32(extendedProperties["WFState"])) {
    state = i;
    } 
else {}
}

try {
    btnApprove.Visible = state.Actions.Approved.NextStateID != null ? true : false;
    btnApprove.Text = state.Actions.Approved.Title.ToString();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    btnApprove.Visible = false;
}
```

`"state"` in `"state.Actions.Approved.NextStateID != null ? true : false;"` is giving the "use of unassigned local variable" even though it assigned.

Comment: also, do you realize that if there is more than one State in `states`, your `state` variable is going to keep getting overwritten as it loops through them, and you don't specify an order?

Comment: As per your logic you are assigning one instance from the list to `state` object if the stateId matches. What if there is no a single instance in the list with matching stateId? In that case the `state` will never be assigned . That's why you are getting this error.

Comment: What you need to do is `State state = null;` and check if `state` is not null before using it in the try block.

Answer (score 1):

What if `states` doesn't have anything in it? `state` might not be populated.

maybe something like:

```
List < State > states = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < List < State >> (json);

if(!states.Any())
    return;

State state;
foreach(State i in states) {
if (i.StateID == Convert.ToInt32(extendedProperties["WFState"])) {
    state = i;
    } 
else {}
}

try {
    btnApprove.Visible = state.Actions.Approved.NextStateID != null ? true : false;
    btnApprove.Text = state.Actions.Approved.Title.ToString();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    btnApprove.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: states is always going to be populated though

Comment: what is json is empty or null? Or can't deserialize to that object?

Comment: That isn't known at compile time though. Even if it could be demonstrated at compile time (it can't) the rules the compiler uses to determine if something is definitely assigned are relatively simple, so it still wouldn't count as definitely assigned.

Comment: I tried and unfortunately it's still showing as unassigned local variable.

Answer (score 0):

The `state` variable would be unassigned if:

- the `states` list is empty, or
- the condition `if (i.StateID == Convert.ToInt32(extendedProperties["WFState"]))` is false for all states in the list.

You need to initialize the `state` variable to `null` (or better yet a valid state value) to avoid the compiler warning.